# AngularJS assign values to items in ng-repeat array using ng-model and retrieve those values

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

This is turning out a lot harder than expected.

I have two arrays: one for products and one for options. Each Product should have its own array of options.

The problem starts when I try to give each product its own options array with its own scope, meaning when one option is selected it only pertains to that product's $scope and not any other.

It was suggested I add [$index] to the array, but this doesn't seem to work. I can't retrieve specific values in this array.

The options array has these ids: (name,price,active). Before I was trying to do this by setting the active boolean to true and filtering those results... but either way would be fine, in a nutshell i need to retrieve the name and price values of the chosen option...

This wasn't the easiest to explain so bear with me... thanks for looking.

**Option view html**

```
<md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
     <img ng-src="{{item.img}}" 
          class="md-card-image" 
          alt="">
     <md-card-content class="content">
          <h2 class="md-title">{{ item.name }}</h2>
          <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
          <md-list>
              <p class="md-subhead">Choose Your Flavor</p>
              <md-divider></md-divider>
              <md-list-item ng-repeat="option in options.results" 
                            layout="row">
                  <p> {{ option.name }} </p>
                  <span flex></span>
                  <p> {{ option.price | currency}} </p>
                  <md-checkbox aria-label="option.active"
                               class="md-accent" 
                               ng-model="item.flavor[$index]">
                  </md-checkbox>
              </md-list-item>
          </md-list>
       </md-card-content>
       <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                      layout-align="end center">
           <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                      aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                      ng-click="remove(item)"                               
                      ng-class="{active:item.active}">
               <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
           </md-button>
       </md-action-bar>
 </md-card>
```

Here is the order html where i am trying to use those values..

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-content>
        <md-list>
            <span class="md-subhead">Review Order</span>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
            <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true" 
                          layout="row">
                <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
                <span flex></span>
                <span>{{ item.price | currency}}</span>
                <span ng-repeat="flavor in item.flavor | filter:true">
                    {{flavor}}
                </span>          
            </md-list-item>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
            <md-list-item layout="row">
                <span>Order Total :</span>
                <span flex></span>
                <span>{{ total(items.results) | currency}}</span>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>   
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the ng-model directive you can create the following functions in your controller

```
$scope.addOption = function(item, opt) {
    var index = item.flavors.indexOf(opt);
    if(index > -1) {
        item.flavors.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else
        item.flavors.push(opt);
}

$scope.checkOption = function(item, opt) {
    return item.flavors.indexOf(option) > -1
}
```

and change your html to

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="option.active"
           class="md-accent" 
            ng-checked="checkOption(item, option)"
           ng-click="addOption(item, option)">
</md-checkbox>
```

you can then access the flavors as follows

```
<div ng-repeat="flavor in item.flavors">[{{flavor.name}} : {{flavor.price}}] </div>
```

You can test the idea [here](https://jsfiddle.net/enlightenmedia/to7jx74w/7/)

Comment: that is a nice solution.. and an easy function to add to my factory.. but how would i go about retrieving the values within {{ item.flavours[option.name] }} ??

Comment: There were a few bugs in the original code, fixed them now and added how you could access them.

Comment: works like a charm... do you know why the checkboxes do not become active until they are unchecked.. i changed the default value to false in your code.. but they only become highlighted after they are unchecked and active is false... wierd... if you have any insight on that would be great but thanks for a good solution

Comment: I am trying to figure that one out too